# Python function for determining whether two words in a string start with the same letter

Tags: python

this is my first post here and I am a complete beginner(only been coding for a week or so) so please pardon me if Ive made some very dumb mistakes

> Write a function takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with the same letter(capitalisation does not matter) and false otherwise

SOLUTION:

```
def prob2(b):
for p,q in b.split():
    if p[0] == q[0]:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False).
```

If I try it with a string like 'hello world', I get the error message:

too many values to unpack, expected 2

But if I try it with a string like 'dc' i get the desired output, which makes it obvious that its splitting the string after each letter, not on the whitespace, which is weird, because i did not make any changes and by default it should be splitting on the whitespace.

Please tell me how I can fix this, thanks!

​

Comment: Try adding a `print(repr(b))` to the beginning of the function.  That will show you exactly what is getting passed to the function, which is probably the problem.

Comment: You don't need a loop: `p,q = b.split()` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.split()` returns a list of space-separated words.  Break this into component steps:

```
seq = b.split()
p, q = seq[0]
if p[0] == q[0]:
    return True
else:
   return False
```

This will work *only* when the first element of `seq` is some iterable of length 2.  In short, a 2-letter string will work, comparing those two letters ... `d` and `c` in your example.

Following the above break-down in your two-word case, we get the attempted assignment

```
p, q = "hello"
```

This tries to unpack 5 characters to two variables, causing your error.

Simply splitting a two-word string requires no loop, as others have shown:

```
p, q = b.split()
```

Or, safer yet, simply slice off the first two words:

```
p, q = seq[:2]
seq = seq[2:]     # remove the first two words from the `split` sequence
```

Also, note that your return can be much simpler: you already evaluated the Boolean result you want in the `if` expression.

```
p, q = seq[:2]
return p[0] == q[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

it may have more items in the list, when you split the string by white space. you could print it out to see

```
def prob2(b):
    p,q = b.split()
    return p[0].lower() == q[0].lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

`for p,q in b.split()` is not doing what you think.

Use `p,q = b.split()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `for p,q in b.split()` this need that every element returned from the `split()` can be unpack in 2, this is the case of `dc->d,c` but each word of `Hello Word` canno't be unpacked in 2

Also you don't need to loop, as you need to look only at the first char, just do

```
def prob2(content):
    words = content.split()
    return len(words) == 2 and words[0].lower() == words[1].lower()
```

Comment: Could you clarify why your code works and mine dosent? For example, when you say first, second = word.split(), the split function here does split on the whitespace, giving you two values to assign to first, second. However, when I say b.split(), why does it not do the same there. What exactly is the for function doing, that's not allowing it to split properly. As I said, im a beginner so it'd be great if I could have clarification on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_the_first_letter_of_two_words(word):
  new_word = word.lower().split()
  if new_word[0][0] == new_word[1][0]:
    return True
  else:
    return False

word1 = 'Hello World'
word2 = 'World wide'
check_the_first_letter_of_two_words(word1)
check_the_first_letter_of_two_words(word2)
```